# Why are ConTeXt entries greyed out in Texworks bundled with a full MikTeX installation?

Tags: miktex, context, windows, texworks, makeindex

I installed `MikTeX` on `Windows 10`. I made sure every single package is installed and updated them to the latest version. When I open `TeXworks` bundled with `MikTeX`, I have a handful of options to compile my file. However three `ConTeXt` entries cannot be selected. This is the entire list of entries. How can I enable them?

```
pdfTeX
pdfLaTeX
pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX
LuaTeX
LuaLaTeX
LuaLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX
XeTeX
XeLaTeX
XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX
upTeX (ptex2pdf)
upLaTeX (ptex2pdf)
% ConTeXt (LuaTeX) 
% ConTeXt (pdfTeX)
% ConTeXt (XeTeX)
BibTeX
Biber
MakeIndex
```

Comment: miktex doesn't contain context. If you want to use it you will have to install a standalone context.

Comment: For reference, here's [the installation guide for ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation). You can also install TeX Live since ConTeXt is included there too.